# How to queue threads in python sequentially

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am writing a small testing GUI program in python (pyqt5). i have 5 functions that do different tasks.
I want to queue the each function, currently they are being executed at the same time,I want the functions to be executed sequentially.

for each function I am making a thread, so that my GUI doesnt freeze.
The next function and thread should be called once the 1st thread and function has finished their job.

I am not sure how to do this. here is my code snippet for it.

```
def ping_echo(self):
        ping_all()
    
    def rx_tx_call(self):
        rx_tx_check()
    
    def leistung_output(self):
        final_power_output()
        time.sleep(2)
        close_port_L()
    
    def set_parameter(self):
        self.write_parameter(self)

    def f_update(self):
        software_install_switch(ip, file)
```

These are the functions that need to be executed in a sequence from top to bottom(FIFO)
Here are the threads that call the function

```
def thread_ping(self):
        #self.ping_echo()
        self.ping_thread = Thread(target=self.ping_echo)
        self.ping_thread.start()
    
    def thread_rxtx(self):
        #rx_tx_check()
        self.rxtx_thread = Thread(target=self.rx_tx_call)
        self.rxtx_thread.start()
    
    def thread_leistung(self):
        #final_power_output()
        #time.sleep(2)
        #close_port_L()
        self.leistung_thread = Thread(target=self.leistung_output)
        self.leistung_thread.start()
    
    def thread_parameter(self):
        #self.write_parameter()
        self.parameter_thread = Thread(target=self.write_parameter)
        self.parameter_thread.start()

    def thread_fupdate(self):
        self.fupdate_thread = Thread(target=self.f_update)
        self.fupdate_thread.start()
```

After the button on the GUI is clicked i was hoping these would be executed sequentially but they all execute at the same time. How do i sequentially execute them.
so the first task should finish and then the next task should begin.

```
        self.ui.button_TestStartenVA.clicked.connect(self.thread_ping)
        self.ui.button_TestStartenVA.clicked.connect(self.thread_rxtx)
        self.ui.button_TestStartenVA.clicked.connect(self.thread_leistung)
        self.ui.button_TestStartenVA.clicked.connect(self.thread_parameter)
        self.ui.button_TestStartenVA.clicked.connect(self.thread_fupdate)
```

Any help would be much apreciated. if you could give me a code example that would be super helpful too. I am not sure how to use the Queue modul in python. I am a newbie to programming.

Comment: Instead of connecting all functions to separate thread constructors, why don't you create *one* thread that points to a *single* function that calls the related functions in sequence?

Comment: @musicamante Yeah that worked, i dont know why i did not think of this basic idea, thank you